# Strange output, printing same variables

Tags: android

I'm experimenting with android and this seems kinda strange to me.

Below is part of my code and the output i get.

[Main XML](http://pastebin.com/bfzeeqU8)

[Activity XML (on call)](http://pastebin.com/raV16MS7)

[Main.java](http://pastebin.com/r8tGvqd2)

[Activity.java](http://pastebin.com/LQG3y113)

Here's my issues now.

I know that the database will be the same with the IP.
Made it this way for now because for some reason if i change it to
`String database_login = editText_database.getText().toString();`
for some reason the app crashes.

But the thing i REALLY cant understand is the fact that the output where everything works fine except the username.

For username i get the same value as the password.
IP printin out fine, port fine, database (for some reason app crashes when using it's variable), username (same with password field), password just fine.

Thank you

Comment: You have a mismatch between your xml id `@+id/edit_databse` and the `R.id.edit_database` you are using. That is why it crashes.

Comment: my god, true, but still doesn't explain the username-password being the same...

Comment: Maybe `EXTRA_PASSWORD` is equal to `EXTRA_USERNAME`. Check it

Comment: Checked 4 times already, removed the password field completely, username showed up fine, rewrote BOTH from the start still the same

Comment: The username is showing like the password right?

Comment: Yes username showing up the same with password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40305/discussion-between-sherif-elkhatib-and-teris-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

1. You have a mismatch between your xml id @+id/edit_databse and the R.id.edit_database you are using. That is why it crashes.
2. `EXTRA_PASSWORD` is equal to `EXTRA_USERNAME`: Check their declaration. If you use eclipse hold Control and while holding it, use the mouse to click on EXTRA_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 1):

In your main_xml you have:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_databse"
    ...
    android:inputType="text" />
```

See `android:id=@+id/edit_databse`. It's spelled wrong. Maybe that is the reason for crashing.

Comment: Yes like Sherif mentioned above solved that, the other one is the one thats really bothering me :P

Comment: I haven't seen Sherif answer, just gone straight to code. Everything looks fine with your code. I'm not shore why that is happening. Have you cleaned your project? Do you input same values for `username` and `password` (people sometimes make this kind of mistakes)? If you find a solution please post it so see what was the problem, I'm very interested.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, the problem was on the declaration of those two, `public final static String EXTRA_USERNAME = "com.example.myfirstapp.username_login";
 public final static String EXTRA_PASSWORD = "com.example.myfirstapp.password_login";`
they were the same before